# First word not broken in marginpar

Tags: marginpar, wordbreak

```
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1em}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1cm}
\newcommand{\sidetopic}[1]{\marginpar{\setstretch{.5}\begin{footnotesize}#1\end{footnotesize}}}
```

and

`\sidetopic{Grundbegriffe von Graphen}` output

[image].

The first word doesn't get broken but the rest of the text does... Is there anything wrong with my code? Any ideas on how to fix it (except for manually breaking the word)?

Comment: You can fix this by switching to LuaLaTeX... Traditional engines never break the first word in a paragraph.

Comment: or use `\hspace*{0pt}Grundbegriffe ...` so the word is seen

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks it works :)